# Django passing multiple ids through URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For POST/GET (etc) requests I have the following URL for one user:

`v1/users/userid123`

registered as so:

`router.register(r"v1/users", accounts_views_v1.UserViewSet)`

What modifications should I make so that I can pass multiple user IDs like:
`v1/users/?ids=["userid123","userid456"]`?

It worked without any modification for another model of mine, with the same criteria, but this one keeps giving a 403 error (before even going into the method!) when I try it

Code per request:
My viewset is insanely long, here's the beginning though

```
class UserViewSet(MultipleDBModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.none()

    @workspace_specific
    def get_queryset(self):
        group_ids = json.loads(self.request.query_params.get("group_id", "[]"))
        queryset = None
        if group_ids:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(group_memberships__group__in=group_ids).distinct()
        else:
            queryset = User.objects.all()

        return queryset.select_related("workspace_role").prefetch_related(
            "group_memberships__group_role", "group_memberships__group"
        )
```

and my URLS:

```
PREFIX = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK_ROUTER_PREFIX
if PREFIX:
    PREFIX = r"^" + str(PREFIX) + r"/"
router = BulkRouter()
single_object_router = SingleObjectRouter()
lazy_single_object_create_or_update_router = LazySingleObjectCreateOrUpdateRouter()
...
router.register(r"v1/users", accounts_views_v1.UserViewSet)
...
urlpatterns = [...]
```

GET method:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True, exclude=None)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True, exclude=None)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I found the kink, this function wraps all the others:
`def permission_check_wrapper(self, request, *args, pk=None, **kwargs)`
of course, when there are IDs instead of one pk, it doesn't work - how can I pass ids instead?

Comment: Share your ```urls.py``` and ```views.py```.

Comment: Share how you handle the `GET` parameters as well

Comment: Added all that stuff, but it's very classic

Comment: Seems to me more of a question about drf than django itself.